# Laravel cannot load the specific User model

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php, bluehost

I have just uploaded a Laravel 4.1 application to Bluehost, and since I cannot login into my app, it keeps telling me that my User class doesn't exist.

I'm using psr-4 to load my specific dir/namespace and inside that I have created my own User class under the model dir.

I have also changed the auth.config file pointing the User model in the specific dir.

I checked the composer autoload_classmap which keeps loading the original app/model/User class. I don't know if this is incorrect since it is the same in my local dev ambient.

Here's the funny thing. Only the User model doesn't work, the others, declared in the same namespace are working as expected.

Looks like Laravel doesn't consider the auth.config file.

Someone can give a hand with this?

Comment: Probably an issue with "case sensitive" filenames. Is your development environment windows?

Comment: Nope, it's ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What was your developing environment? Were you using a Mac? If so, Mac is case insensitive. I ran into the exact same issue!! Just double check all paths.

Comment: I have found the error, it was the class name, instead of User I typed Users. Galactic Facepalm.

Comment: Running a `composer dump-autoload` may help